# parse json array string using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to parse this json using logstash.

> {"name":"bob","last":"builder", "atts":"{\"a\":111, \"b\":222}"}
>
> {
>        "name" => "bob",
>        "last" => "builder"
>        "atts" => {
>             "a" => 111,
>             "b" => 222}    }

Comment: Please add more details about your use case. So then we can help you out.  And also add the sample of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options!

**Parsing JSON using Logstash**

If you want to parse JSON using logstash- would refer to the logstash plugin here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

To achieve this- you'd be toying with the filter part of your logstash.conf:

```
filter {
   json {
     source => "message"
   }
}
```

there are more examples of json decoding in that link.

**Parsing JSON using Filebeat**

Your other option would be to decode json on the filebeat side before it gets into logstash. Relevant links:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parse-json-data-with-filebeat/80008/5

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parse-json-data-with-filebeat/80008/7

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-read-json-file-using-filebeat-and-send-it-to-elasticsearch/91802

Here's a sample filebeat.yml for this situation:

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    paths:
      - 'path to the log directory you want to track'
    enter code here
    input_type: log
    json.keys_under_root: true
    json.add_error_key: true
    fields:
        log_type: 'type of log'

    processors:
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        process_array: true

    - add_tags:
        tags:
            - 'tag in elastic'

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1

output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["where logstash is running"]
  index: 'your index'

  codec.json:
    pretty: true
    escape_html: false

#================================ Processors =====================================
# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.
processors:
- decode_json_fields:
    fields: ["message"]
    process_array: true
```

```
json.keys_under_root: true
json.add_error_key: true
```

and

```
processors:
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        process_array: true
```

does the trick.